# Casting output in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I get as output `""10076053346""` in postgresql. This is in json format. 
I want to convert it into `"10076053346"` or this format `10076053346`. 
So basically I want to convert it from json to int or text. 
I have tried out the various cast functions but they dont seem to be working for me. 
Any hints and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trim the quotes and then cast to int `TRIM(data, '"')::int`, although the example value `10076053346` is out of the integer range, so you should go for a `bigint` or `numeric` instead.

```
SELECT TRIM(data, '"')::bigint;
```